# SOA SMPP driver not functioning as well

Tags: oracle, soa, smpp, oim

In our Oracle IDM environment we implemented OTP to send SMS to users.

So we installed SMPP Driver on SOA server with SMS Vendor and everything  is ok and OTP is working well.
But when we changed SMS Vendor to another one, the OTP sometimes successes but Mostly fails. Also 'Read Time Out' exception is thrown every 30 second.

Another important thing, when we tried to send SMS to the new vendor using standlone smpp client on the same server it's working fine.

Why the client can send sms perfectly but using SOA server not?

**The following Excpetion is shown every 30 second :**

```
<Aug 1, 2017 8:24:48 AM GMT> <Error> <oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.smpp> <SDP-25700> <An unexpected exception was caught.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.readCommand(SMPPDriver.java:715)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.readAnswer(SMPPDriver.java:771)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.access$700(SMPPDriver.java:145)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver$SMPPReceivingReader.run(SMPPDriver.java:1813)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
at weblogic.connector.work.LongRunningWorkRequest.run(LongRunningWorkRequest.java:29)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**The following  Excpetion is shown when OTP sending is failed :**

```
<Aug 1, 2017 8:25:21 AM GMT> <Error> <oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.smpp> <SDP-25700> <An unexpected exception was caught.
oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver$ConnectFailedException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.openTransmitterSocket(SMPPDriver.java:2961)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:3146)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:2849)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPDriver.send(SMPPDriver.java:2724)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.smpp.SMPPManagedConnection.send(SMPPManagedConnection.java:95)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.DriverConnectionImpl.send(DriverConnectionImpl.java:41)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean.onMessage(DriverDispatcherBean.java:296)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3298.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy507.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean_xfokw2_MDOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDOMethodInvoker.invoke(MDOMethodInvoker.java:35)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.dispatcher.DriverDispatcherBean_xfokw2_MDOImpl.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.jmsmessagereceiver.ResourceAdapterImpl$RaMessageListener.onMessage(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:167)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.jms.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
at weblogic.work.j2ee.J2EEWorkManager$WorkWithListener.run(J2EEWorkManager.java:184)
```

Comment: I think it's SOA related, have you tried to ask on SOA Oracle forum?

Comment: Not yet, i will do it.
But I will be glad if I found solution anywhere

Comment: Have you taken a look at the jvm options to see if there is something that conflicts with the new SMS vendor?

Comment: @Berkley previously with the old vendor we didn't set special jvm options for it, and it was working fine. Now with the new vendor we expect the same thing, so we kept jvm options as it is, but it fails most of the time.